# Load Data from spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel

I want to load data from a spreadsheet and use the data in my C# code.

In my spreadsheet, I have multiple URLs in separate columns which I want to use in my code.

## Excel Sheet:

Column1     |     Column2

abc.com      |     /test

xyz.com      |     /test

wry.com      |     /test

## C# Code:

```
var pageManager = PageManager.GetManager();
var pageNodes = pageManager.GetPageNodes();
foreach (PageNode page in pageNodes)
{
    if (page.Page != null && page.Page.IsBackend == false && page.GetUrl() == "<data from first column>")
    {
        pageManager.AddItemUrl<PageNode>(page, "<data from second column>", false, true);
        pageManager.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you posted code... Is your code working? If not where is the problem? If it does what is your question? Btw, never heard of PageManager

Comment: @RandRandom I am sorry i wans't clear enough. in my code, i mentioned that i need data from spreadsheet. All i just want to load data from spread sheet and put the data from columns in my for each loop